# Rails 5.0.7.2 MIME::Type Class has no method `lookup`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types

I am running Rails 5.0.7.2. In my project I have so far always set the mime type like follows:

```
render :js => File.read(js_file), :content_type => 'application/javascript'
```

(for example). It appears, however, I shouldn't be doing it this way but by using the Class MIME::Type. On Rails console I can find it and print its methods. I used `(MIME::Type.methods - Object.methods).sort`. It only gives me three methods: `match`, `simplified` and `i18n_key`. The documentation says there should be methods `lookup` and `lookup_by_extension`.

When I try using MIME::Type.lookup('application/javascript') in my code I get the same error: as if the method wasn't defined.

Does anybody know what is the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Mime::Type.lookup('application/javascript')` does return something in my console (MIME constant is not recognized, but Mime is)

Comment: @Maxence Incredible. As easy as that. `Mime` instead of `MIME`. Thanks a lot! The only thing I'd like to know is, why do both `MIME::Type` and `Mime::type` exist? But that's something I can research some other time.

Comment: Try running `MIME.method(:match).source_location`. My guess is that its the [ruby-mime-types gem](https://github.com/mime-types/ruby-mime-types) as `MIME` is not part of the Ruby standard library - nor Rails 5. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c4d3e202e10ae627b3b9c34498afb45450652421/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxence's comment solved the problem. Typing `Mime::Type` instead of `MIME::Type` is all it took. I should have been more careful when reading the docs. Bit awkward that `MIME::Type` gave me a result other than nil, or else I would have found my error long ago.